# GATE 2008: Time Complexity of Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

You are given the post-order traversal, P of a binary search tree on the n elements 1,2,.........,n. you have to determine the unique binary search tree that has P as its post-order traversal. what is the time complexity of the **MOST EFFICIENT algorithm** for doing this?

> (a) theeta(logn)
>
> (b) theeta(n)
>
> (c) theeta(nlogn)
>
> (d) none of the above, as tree cannot be uniquely determined

answer is **(b)**, please explain the solution. if we have been given post-order traversal don't we need to apply `sorting(O(nlogn))` to compute in-order?

Comment: Are the elements added to the tree in numerical order?

Comment: No, we don't need to compute in-order. Why would we want to? In order to come up with an algorithm, try to reason why the tree should be indeed unique.

Comment: we have been given only post-order traversal, as we know in-order traversal is always gives a sorted list in ascending order and we need in-order and post/pre order traversal so i thought by applying sorting on post-traversal order we can get in-order

Comment: @Marichyasana this is only given information

Comment: I googled the interwebs using the first paragraph of your problem statement. There is a page that explains this, but using pre-order. Are you asking for an explanation of that page which is a guide to doing it post-order?  `http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-bst-from-given-preorder-traversa/`

Comment: @Marichyasana prior to posting here i visited that link but couldn't understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to sort it.

In the post-order traversal you can find some hidden info. Like:

- The last element is always the tree root
- All the previous elements greater than the root are part of the right subtree. All the elements lesser are part of the left subtree.
- You can apply the above rules recursively.

This is only true because you have only distinct elements. If there were repetitions, the tree for the traversal couldn't be unique.

Here's an example implementation (in Python) that shows this:

```py
from collections import deque

def visit(in_queue, limit = None):
    if len(in_queue) == 0 or in_queue[-1] < limit:
        return None
    root = in_queue.pop()
    right = visit(in_queue, max(root, limit))
    left = visit(in_queue, limit)

    if left is None and right is None:
        return root
    else:
        return (left, root, right)

def print_graphviz(tree):
    if not isinstance(tree, tuple):
        return tree
    left = print_graphviz(tree[0])
    right = print_graphviz(tree[2])

    if left is not None: print tree[1], '->', left
    if right is not None: print tree[1], '->', right
    return tree[1]

def make_tree(post_order):
    return visit(deque(post_order))

print 'digraph {'
print print_graphviz(make_tree([0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 8, 7, 5]))
print '}'
```

Run like this:

```
python test.py | dot -Tpng | display
```

And you'll have a nice tree output:

[image: tree]

Comment: it means in case if we have post-order with distinct elements we can always create a B.S.T in O(n) time and answer to my above mentioned question should be (b). please confirm.
Can we apply the same procedure in reverse for Pre-order traversal to construct B.S.T?

Comment: @GamRaj Yes, it is (b). And yes, the rationale is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the central element (it's the root of this subtree) and the left tree will be constructed using smaller numbers and right tree using bigger numbers (everything using recursion).
In pseudocode:

make_BST(T[]):

1. if in T we have less than 2 elements: return the tree with this element
2. otherwise: return tree which root is central element from T (let's name it x), the left son will be make_BST(elements from T smaller than x) and right son will be make_BST(elements from T bigger than x)

Of course you should only remember whole T and the left and right border of the considered range.

The complexity of this algorithm will be T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) + O(1) so T(n) = O(n) so that's the same complexity as in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

In post oders traversal, root can always be found at last node, so it will take o(logn) time complexity.
Now, in quick sort, take root as pivot and the elements less than the root will be at left side and rests will be in right side, suppose there are k such elements which are lesser than the root.
So, the recurrence equation is,

T(n)=T(k)+T(n-k-1)+O(logn)

Now, in worst case put k=0, so the equation will look like

T(n)=T(n-1)+O(logn)

By solving it, we get

T(n)=O(logn!) [O(logn)= O(log1)+O(log2)+O(log3)+...+O(logn)]
 which will be less than O(logn)+O(logn)+...+O(logn).

So, we can get the upper O(nlogn).

answer:- theta(n logn)